# Materialize Select Option not working Fully

Tags: php, html-select, materialize

I am using **materialize** with **php** to create options inside the **select** Dynamically. It creates all the options of the select with no problem. These options are then used to populate another select Option.
The only problem is that whenever it has to create a large number of options inside a select it will create them but only a limited number will work.

**Example:** if the first **select** loads 10 options only 6 will be selectable and the rest will not work. 
Therefore I can not use the last option in this case option 10 to populate the second select.

If I don't use **materialize** it works fine with no problems. As soon as I try to use **materialize** then it becomes a problem.

Can anyone help on how I can around these issue.